# Passing text value from html page to php page

Tags: php, javascript, html

I know this question is similar to other questions, I did hours of research yet I could not figure out a solution, please help me find a solution.

I want to pass textfield value from html to php textfield but instead of value, the php code is shown as output.

Page 1:

```
<body>
<form action="fare1.php" method="post">


  <input name="address1" id="address1" type="text" size="15" value="City" /> 
  <input name="" type="submit" />

    </form>

</body>
```

Page 2:

```
<body>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Instructions</h1>
    <table width="200">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input type="text" name="from" id="from" value="<?php echo $_POST['address1'];     ?>" /></td>
  </tr> 
</table>
     <!-- end .content --></div>  
</body>
```

I tried using hidden fields, using javascript function and many other things but I couldn't reach a solution to my problem :(

Thanks!

Edit...

It seems I am having trouble with PHP itself, I am trying to figure it out now. PHP is not running in my system. Please let me know if you know of any free hosting sites which provides php support, I tried 50webs, it is saving the php files instead of opening it.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that PHP is running at the server?

Comment: Is the server configured for PHP? Does page 2 have the correct extension

Comment: What? It literally prints "<?php ..." in the output? That means PHP is not run at all. Can you run other PHP scripts?

Comment: if you are using `.html` as the extension of your files, most servers aren't set-up to handle this, you should use `.php` - if you already are then as the others state, you'll need to make sure PHP is actually running. You can do this by creating a `test.php` file with the following content `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. If when you visit that page you get the php code, then you do not have php running.

Comment: god save us from these hard coders......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the php is running on your server, fare1.php should execute without showing any php code for the output. If it is, then your server doesn't support the php. I suggest you download xampp. Its a free and open web server that supports php.